# Rails 3.0 sms_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

On which file do I add the following configurations for Rails 3?

## sms_fu = SMSFu::Client.configure(:delivery => :action_mailer)

So I can do a sms_fu.deliver("5558675309","at&t","message") in one of my models?

Is there other code to add like include sms_fu somewhere?

Accessing SMSFu from the console works fine. But doing a <%= carrier_collection %> gives a no method error.